# How to add elevation shadow to SmallTopAppBar in Material3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How do I add an elevation drop shadow to the `SmallTopAppBar` in Material3? With the `TopAppBar` in Material2, you simply had to specify the `elevation` parameter, but how do you do it with Material3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with jetpack compose you typically have 3 options for shadow elevation:

1. The composable itself has a shadow elevation (Material3 uses color as mentioned by Ben)
2. The use of Modifier.shadow(elevation = X.dp)
3. Wrapping whatever is needed in a Surface composable which will give you most of the UI freedom needed (Though at this point might as well make a custom element yourself)

Hope I was able to help!

Answer (score 2):

this will add an elevation effect to your app bar

```
TopAppBar(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .shadow(
                elevation = 5.dp, //or whatever value 
                spotColor = Color.DarkGray,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
            ))
```

[image: top appbar with elevation]

Answer (score 1):

The M3 toolbars no longer use a shadow to elevate themselves. In M3 the color changes as you scroll to differentiate the toolbar from the rest of the content.

There is a sample available in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#SmallTopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior))

Comment: Can you specify a border for the `SmallTopAppBar` in M3?

Comment: I assume Modifier.border() works but I haven't tried

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the shadow from the modifier as below, but make sure to set the container color of the app bar to have the shadow effect.

```
CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    modifier = Modifier.shadow(5.dp),
    title = {
        Text(text = title)
    },
    colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
        containerColor = Color.White
    )
)
```